# Encountered Issues Using Multiple Methods on the Same Code

Tags: java

I am a fairly new programmer in Java and am currently learning about how to incorporate multiple methods in one code. The goal of this practice activity is to use several different methods to:

-Create two arrays (one for employee names and another for how much that employee sold)

-Find the average of total sales

-Find the highest sale number

-Find the name of the Employee(s) with the highest sale count (and print "hooray" for every employee that had the highest sale count)

```
import java.util.*;

public class MethodActivity{

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] names={"Employee A", "Employee B", "Employee C", "Employee D", "Employee E", "Employee F", "Employee G", "Employee H", "Employee I", "Employee J"};
    System.out.print("Enter the sales numbers, in dollars,  for each employee: ");
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    int num2 = sc.nextInt();
    int num3 = sc.nextInt();
    int num4 = sc.nextInt();
    int num5 = sc.nextInt();
    int num6 = sc.nextInt();
    int num7 = sc.nextInt();
    int num8 = sc.nextInt();
    int num9 = sc.nextInt();
    int num10 = sc.nextInt();
    double[] sales={num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10};
    return double[] sales;
    return String[] names;
 }

    public static double getAverage(double[] sales){
        double average=(num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10)/10;
        return average;
   }
    public static int getHighestSale(double[] sales){
        double highest = sales[0];
        int locationOfHighest=0;
        if(sales[1]>highest){
            highest=sales[1];
            locationOfHighest=1;
        }else if(sales[2]>highest){
            highest=sales[2];
            locationOfHighest=2;
        }else if(sales[3]>highest){
            highest=sales[3];
            locationOfHighest=3;
        }else if(sales[4]>highest){
            highest=sales[4];
            locationOfHighest=4;
        }else if(sales[5]>highest){
            highest=sales[5];
            locationOfHighest=5;
        }else if(sales[6]>highest){
            highest=sales[6];
            locationOfHighest=6;
        }else if(sales[7]>highest){
            highest=sales[7];
            locationOfHighest=7;
        }else if(sales[8]>highest){
            highest=sales[8];
            locationOfHighest=8;
        }else{
            highest=sales[9];
            locationOfHighest=9;
        }
        return highest;
    }
    public static String showName(String[] names){
        String nameOfHighest = "";
        String hooray = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
            if (i=locationOfHighest){
                nameOfHighest=nameOfHighest+names[i]+", ";
                hooray = ""+"hooray ";
            }else{
                nameOfHighest=nameOfHighest;
            }
        }
        return nameOfHighest;
    }

 public static void (String[] args){
    System.out.println("The average sales for today was: "+average);
    System.out.println(nameOfHighest+" made the highest sales of "+highest);
    System.out.println(hooray);
 }
}
```

However, when I run the program, I got these errors. The thing is, I don't really understand what they mean:

```
MethodActivity.java:20: error: '.class' expected
            return double[] sales;
                            ^

MethodActivity.java:21: error: '.class' expected
            return String[] names;
                            ^

MethodActivity.java:75: error: <identifier> expected
    public static void (String[] args){
```

I would really appreciate if someone could clarify what these mean, since I'm still quite confused by the concept of a multi method code. And, if you could, maybe point out any other issues or fixable elements in my code (since I know my code might look pretty sloppy to someone with programming experience and I could really use some pointers). Thank you for your time.

Comment: You definitely need to have a look at loops.

Comment: just do a `return sales;`

Comment: also it is `public static void main` => main is missing

Comment: There are so many errors in your code (sorry). I think you should go a step back and start learning java with another book/excercises. Then you will see how to return a value, which return type is expected and were you have access to which variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this both returns. 
There are two problem in your code:

1) java method can have only one return statement.

2)  it is main method and because of it returns void type. void means no return type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather using separate method for printing "public static void (String[] args), print those in main method itself. 
Also refer answer by iMBMT.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodActivity {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number of employees : ");
    int totalEmployeeCount = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("## totalEmployeeCount : " + totalEmployeeCount);
    String[] employeeNames = new String[totalEmployeeCount];
    int[] employeeSoldCount = new int[totalEmployeeCount];
    String name;
    int count;
    for (int index = 0; index < totalEmployeeCount; index++) {
        System.out.print("Enter employee name : ");
        name = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter employee sale count : ");
        count = sc.nextInt();
        employeeNames[index] = name;
        employeeSoldCount[index] = count;
    }

    System.out.println("---------------- Pringting all info ----------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < employeeNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("name : " + employeeNames[i] + " & sale count : " + employeeSoldCount[i]);
    }

    findTheAverageOfTotalSales(employeeSoldCount);
    findTheHighestSaleNumber(employeeSoldCount);

}

private static void findTheAverageOfTotalSales(int[] employeeSoldCount) {
    for (int saleCount : employeeSoldCount) {
        System.out.println("Write your own code ...");
    }
}

private static void findTheHighestSaleNumber(int[] employeeSoldCount) {
    for (int saleCount : employeeSoldCount) {
        System.out.println("Write your own code ...");
    }
}
```

}